# Scaled test data value range is much different than the scaled train data

Tags: time-series, normalization, scales, feature-scaling

I am trying to create an LSTM model for time series prediction.
I am using MinMaxScaler (from the library sklearn for python) for scaling the data.
At first, I didn't know that you shouldn't fit the test data to the scaler, so I fitted it with the whole dataset(train and test) and the results were decent, some of them pretty good.
But then I realized that it is forbidden to fit the scaler with the test data so I only fitted it with the train data. The problem is that transforming the test data with the scaler gives values in a very different range than the train data that the model is trained on.
For example: for one feature, the training data is between 0 and 1, but scaling the test data of this feature gives values between 8 and 9.

As a result, the model cannot produce a result that makes sense and after I inverse transform the forecasts, they are in range that doesn't make sense. (40-60 when it should be around 200)

And the test data isn't so different from the train data:

**train data:**
mean: 240.7

min: 225.8

max: 251.9

scaled range: 0-1

**test data:**

mean: 230.4

min: 230.4

max: 251.6

scaled range(using the scaler fitted with the train data): 8.24-9

Does anyone knows what should I do in order to solve this problem?

**Edit: I found out the problem was my implementation for scaling each series.
Make sure you don't use/fit the same scaler for different features of your data.**

For example:
If you have a dataset of temperatures and humidity, make sure you created a scaler for each one of them. Then fit each scaler with the data of the corresponding feature.
The code for scaling with sklearn's MinMaxScaler can look like this:

```
temparture_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
humidity_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

temparture_scaler.fit(temparture_train_data)
humidity_scaler.fit(humidity_train_data)
```

Comment: Did you use the scaling factors from training data to scale your out-of-sample data, or did you use out-of-sample data to calculate scaling factors for your out-of-sample data?

Comment: I used the scaling factors from the training data to scale the out-of-sample data.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "Make sure you don't use/fit the same scaler for different series"?

Comment: Oh, what I meant is not to fit and use the same scaler for different features in the dataset. I accidentally fitted one scaler instead of creating a new one for each feature.
@Dave I will edit the sentence again so it will be clear.